# Phone authentication creates new account and breaks link on firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am linkning an email with phone authenticated user account on firebase as per code given. I am first creating a new user using phone sms authentication, after that trying to associate an email with this user since I want to also let user login using email. For email I am using email link verification. Linking takes place and I can see two authentication methods for a user in dashboard. Now when I logout and try to login using email link authentication firebase creates a new user and now I have two user one by phone and other by email.

```js
 val credential:AuthCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email,link)
mAuth!!.currentUser?.linkWithCredential(credential)?.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
if (task.isSuccessful) {
       Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success")
       val user = task.result?.user

} else {
       Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
       Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}
}
```

I have been banging my head on Firebase documents since hours now but not clue why this is happening . Neither could I find any post related to this.
Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are planning for two step authentication in app with phone and email. Please see this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44966449/7672400 .
I've implemented the same. It might help you

Comment: I am trying to link the account as per google document and that works , but it breaks the link if I relogin using email after this if I relogin using phone

Comment: I am not sure your method will work since above mentioned issue was accepted by firebase support team as they could reproduce it , this surely is an issue with firebase .

Comment: @vishaldharankar This happens due to security reasons. I've researched a year ago  on the same issue. Since email accounts are considered as primary authentication source. If you tried doing the same procedure with fb and after that google auth with same account. It will create two different accounts. I'm just searching for the reference where i've read the answer

Comment: there has to be some solution for that